# Ridiculous CSS media query issue

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design, media-queries

I am at a loss with why one page on a site that just went live is misbehaving on iPhone (and possibly others at 320 to 480 px wide.

I have used various simulators that have never let me down before (screenfly & iphone5 simulator) plus I have tested the responsiveness using browser resize and for some reason none of these methods can replicate the issue so I cannot find a way to correct the problem. I have cleared my cache and tried from a different phone.

The Problem:

Visit (site removed) from a phone and notice that this is the only page on the website that does not fill the devices screen. Visit any other page and you will see that the rest all fill the page normally.

If someone can point me in a direction to reproduce the problem (not on a phone) where I can access developer tools I should be able to correct the problem on my own.

I have tried reviewing my code to see what is different about that page in comparison to every other page and cannot find what appears to be causing the problem.

Some help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome on Phone it's ok!

Check your settings about responsive and specific browsers settings in CSS..

Good Luck, please give photo from Phone.

Comment: I just added a screenshot from Chrome on iphone 4. Rest of the pages are fine, just this one seems to be forcing itself to 70% width.

Comment: Heh, if browser have px x px, give 100% width in body and text box(div).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the issue. Was able to find a div element with in the contact form that had a fixed width and although the content within the form was properly set the div was pushing the entire page over.